# Get Ruby pure class name without parent name, any direct method for it?

Tags: ruby

I often need to get the pure class name of an object, as code below:

```
class Foo
    class Bar

    end
end
obj = Foo::Bar.new
puts obj.class.name  # It shows "Foo::Bar", while what I want is just "Bar"
```

I know it can be done by obj.class.name.split('::').last, but, shouldn't be there a method just return "Bar" ?

Comment: `Foo.constants[0]` gives the symbol `:Bar`. However, I can't think of a way to construct a message to your instance, `obj`, that does the same, other than splitting the name string.

Comment: What do you use "Bar" for?

Comment: For example: I have 3 classes, Eat::Apple, Eat::Orange, Eat::Banana,  then obj = "Eat::#{fruit}".constantize.new.   

I'm not sure which fruit I'm Eating, so I need to get obj.class.name for judgement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes don't really have "names" in Ruby. A class is an object like any other object, it gets assigned to variables like any other object. A class doesn't have a name, just like a number or a string doesn't have a name.

Take this example:

```
foo = Class.new

Bar = foo
Baz = foo

Bar = nil
remove_const :Bar
```

What should the "name" of the class be in this example?

Well, there *is* a method called `name` in the `Module` class. What it does is the following: *if* the class object has been assigned to a constant for the first time, the name of that constant (note that even *that* is a fuzzy concept!) becomes the name of the class, otherwise the name will just be `nil`.

Expanding on the example above:

```
foo = Class.new

foo.name
# => nil

Bar = foo

foo.name
# => 'Bar'
Bar.name
# => 'Bar'

Baz = foo

Baz.name
# => 'Bar'

Bar = nil
remove_const :Bar

foo.name
# => 'Bar'
```

Here's another example:

```
foo = Class.new
Bar = foo
Baz = foo

class Baz
  class Quux; end

  Xyzzy = Quux
end

foo::Xyzzy.name
# => 'Bar::Quux'
```

Note that even though `Quux` is defined inside `Baz` and accessed via `foo::Xyzzy` it still prints `Bar::Quux` as its name.

Also, two different classes can have the same name:

```
Foo = Class.new

Bar = Foo

Foo = nil
remove_const :Foo

Foo = Class.new

Baz = Foo

Foo = nil
remove_const :Foo

Bar.name
# => Foo

Baz.name
# => Foo

Bar == Baz
# => false
```

The "name" of a class is simply a debugging help for human readers, you should *never* use it for anything else, and never use it programmatically (or even depend on a specific structure of the string).

Answer (score 4):

In vanilla Ruby, I'm pretty sure `class.name.split('::').last` is the best way to go. But if you happen to be using ActiveSupport (if you're on Rails, this library will be loaded) there is an inflector called [demodulize](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveSupport/Inflector/demodulize).

```
class Foo
    class Bar
    end
end
obj = Foo::Bar.new
puts obj.class.name.demodulize # => Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

based on [thomax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26058070/868273) answer i've researched it a bit...

```rb
require 'benchmark'

class String
  def demodulize
    self[(rindex('::') || -2) + 2..-1]
  end

  def split_last
    split('::').last
  end

  def demodulize_vs_split_last n = 5000000
    Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
      x.report('split_last') { n.times { split_last } }
      x.report('demodulize') { n.times { demodulize } }
    end
  end
end
```

and got this:

```
> 'Core::String'.demodulize_vs_split_last
                 user     system      total        real
split_last   1.960688   0.008501   1.969189 (  1.983187)
demodulize   1.807694   0.005815   1.813509 (  1.826771)
```

for short strings it mostly similar

```
> 'Core::Exten::sions::String::Inf::lect::ions'.demodulize_vs_split_last
                 user     system      total        real
split_last   4.386797   0.024131   4.410928 (  4.447739)
demodulize   1.875757   0.005089   1.880846 (  1.895737)
```

but `split('::').last` becomes much slower if your class is nested deeper

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a method to return just the name of the class. Technically, the name is only accurate if it includes any outer modules and classes.

The `#name` method is defined on the `Module` class; [see the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-name) for more information.